# Accessing a random subset of a tuple in C++17 at runtime

Tags: c++, machine-learning, tuples, c++17, decision-tree

I am implementing a decision tree in C++17. I have each record from my dataset stored as a tuple, and a vector containing each of these tuples.

I need to create a subset of the tuples for each unique value found in the field of the tuple.

I understand that accessing elements in a tuple are done at compile-time, so I am wondering if there is any tricks that could be used, or if I should abandon the tuple entirely for this particular project.

Additionally, I need to remove the best attribute from consideration in future iterations when splitting my tree. I thought using an index_sequence might work, but any instances of doing so online were on consecutive numbers (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) instead of random subsets (e.g. 1, 3, 5)

The zip_recordset function takes a vector of tuples (a RecordSet) and creates a tuple of vectors. I thought this would be useful, but I still need which vector to access at runtime.

```
#ifndef __DECISION_TREE
#define __DECISION_TREE

#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <map>

#include "common.h"

namespace ml::dt {
    struct Node {
        bool leaf;
        size_t attr;
        size_t label;
        std::vector<Node> children;
    };

    template<typename T>
    class DecisionTree {
        using RecordSet = typename T::RecordSet;
        using Record = typename T::Record;

        Node head;

        template<typename U>
        double entropy(std::vector<U> attrVec) {
            std::map<U, std::size_t> valMap {};
            for(auto i=0; i<attrVec.size(); ++i) {
                if(valMap.count(attrVec[i]) == 0) {
                    valMap[attrVec[i]] = 1;
                } else {
                    valMap[attrVec[i]]++;
                }
            }

            int totalSize = 0;
            for(auto& [key, val] : valMap) {
                totalSize += val;
            }

            double entropy = 0;
            for(auto& [key, val] : valMap) {
                double p = (static_cast<double>(val)/totalSize);
                entropy += p * std::log2(p);
            }

            return entropy;
        }

        template<auto target>
        Node learn_impl(RecordSet trainSet, std::set<std::size_t> attrList) {
            int pos = 0;
            int neg = 0;
            for(auto& rec : trainSet) {
                if(std::get<target>(rec) == 0) {
                    neg++;
                } else {
                    pos++;
                }
            }

            // If all examples are positive, return +
            if(neg == 0) {
                return Node {true, 0, 1, {}};
            }

            // If all examples are negative, return -
            if(pos == 0) {
                return Node {true, 0, 0, {}};
            }

            // If attr is empty, return label Mode(examples)
            if(attrList.empty()) {
                size_t label = 0;
                if(neg < pos)
                    label = 1;
                return Node {true, 0, label, {}};
            }

            // Get Best Attribute
            size_t bestAttr = 0;
            std::vector<double> entropy_values {};
            auto trainSetVec = T::zip_recordset(trainSet);
            auto clVec = std::get<T::size-1>(trainSetVec);

            std::apply([&](auto& ...v) {
                (entropy_values.emplace_back(entropy(v)),...);
            }, trainSetVec);

            bestAttr = std::distance(entropy_values.begin(), std::min_element(entropy_values.begin(), entropy_values.end()));

            // For every value of attr

                // examples_new = values with attr
                // if examples_new empty
                    // leaf node = mode(examples)
                // else
                    // learn_impl<target>(examples_new, attrList - bestAttr)
        }

    public:
        DecisionTree() = default;

        template<auto target>
        void learn(RecordSet trainSet) {
            std::set<std::size_t> attrList {};
            for(auto i=0; i<T::size; ++i) {
                attrList.emplace(i);
            }
            head = learn_impl<target>(trainSet, attrList);
        }
    };
}

#endif // __DECISION_TREE
```

Is there any way to do this?

### Update

Added longer code example.
Expanded explanation for accessing elements of a tuple.

Comment: `std::index_sequence<1, 3, 5>` is valid. But if you have to support any order, you would have to instantiate 5! (Factorial grows fast) method/class (assuming no other template parameters). You might do "dispatch" to select correct compile type value from runtime value.

Comment: Less explaining text, more code. This question is very hard to follow IMO.

Comment: "*I need to be able to access an index in the tuple chosen at runtime.*" And do what with it? How do you intend to access/manipulate this object?